# Erro InvalidPipeArgument ao usar DatePipe

Tags: banco-de-dados, angular, data, timestamp

Estou a fazer uma uma aplicação em Angular e estou a tentar mostrar uma data, vinda da base de dados, numa tabela.

Eu tenho uma base de dados, tal como referi a cima, que tem um campo para armazenar datas, do tipo Timestamp. Também tenho uma variável, do tipo Date no meu component do Angular, para armazenar essa data.

Ora, quando faço a Interpolation, {{}}, dessa variável no HTML, o browser apresenta a data como Invalid Date e quando uso essa mesma variável, mas com o DatePipe (| date), é apresentada esta mensagem de erro na consola do browser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: veja no código com estás a passar o valor do banco de dados para a variável ou classe, neste momento deve estar convertendo incorretamente, e chega como "Invalid Date" quando vai usar o Angular para exibir no HTML, e se está como uma string com esse texto, vai dar erro ao tentar converter para date usando `| date`

Comment: O mais importante aí vc não colocou na pergunta que é um exemplo de data que vem do banco! Cria uma variável e insere uma data só pra teste e usa o pipe no html se não acusar erro, provavelmente o problema esta nas datas vindo do banco!

Comment: Como o @LeAndrade sugeriu, eu criei uma variável e inseri uma data, meti no HTML e não deu erro. O problema deve vir da base de dados...
O formato das datas na base de dados está assim: `2020-06-09 16:30:42.172000`